# Add secured WMS service to ArcGIS Enterprise web map

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

How can I add a secured WMS (username & password) to a Web Map in ArcGIS Enterprise?
I only see these settings:
[image]

Where can I specify password and username?

Comment: At least a few years ago you just couldn't. However it is quite easy to install GeoServer or MapServer to read the secured WMS and forward the service without authentication.

Comment: You have to secure at the map service level. Under the services directory on the ArcGIS server you, click the lock and add in your credentialing there. You cannot authenticate capabilities of a map service via ArcGIS server. In Portal you can, and in AGOL you can.